# String array - instances of unique values

Tags: java, arrays, counter

I wrote a program that loops through a string array and prints the unique words and their occurrences, and then prints them to a file. This part works perfectly, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the total count of unique words. I have a feeling I need to create an int array for a counter, but I'm not exactly grasping how to do this. Unfortunately I am NOT allowed to use Hashmap, Sets, or Lists; have to stick with Arrays.

```
boolean [] done = new boolean[textfile.length];
for(int i = 0; i<textfile.length; i++){
    if(done[i])
        continue;
    int nb = 0;
    for(int j = i; j < textfile.length; j++){
        if(done[j])
            continue;
        if(textfile[i].equals(textfile[j])){
            done[j] = true;
            nb++;

        }
    }

    pw.println(textfile[i] + "occurs " + nb + " times");
}
```

Comment: are you allowed to use set?

Comment: what is the variable `nb`??

Comment: counts the instances of each unique word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to do as follows-

-Add all the values in an array and sort this array.(so that it will be easy to get unique entry)

-Compare all the elements of sorted array (one by one) with the word to be compared.

-Now while comparing a word in a text file with a word present in an array, maintain a global variable `i.e. counter` which will be incremented on every occurrence of a unique character and will persist the value for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are comparing each word with all the words after it in the file, which takes `O(N^2)` times, you can instead create an array containing all the words, sort it by lexicographic order which takes `O(NlogN)` time, then iterate through the array and count the occurrences of each unique word (if 2 adjacent words are equal, keep counting, otherwise print and reset the counter) which takes `O(N)` times.

Comment: Thanks, this is just the info I needed. I'll see if I can get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could set uniqe_counter outside of first for and increment that every time when nb == 1 before printing

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitializing the variable `nb` in every iteration of the outer loop. thus u end up loosing the count of unique words processed in the last iteration.

U have to place the `int nb = 0;` out side the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

1. Sort the array
2. Go trough the sorted array and remember last unique entry
3. If lastUniqueEntry is different as next entry. UniqueCount + 1
4. Do everything else, like prints the unique words and their occurrences